# using series and parallel tasks in gulp 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am trying to manipulate text before a file is sent to browserify, and I am attempting to use gulp.series to do this. Here's how:

```
gulp.task('dev_urls', function() {
  gulp.src([ 'app/index.js' ])
      .pipe(...)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(...))

gulp.task('build_dev',
  gulp.series('dev_urls', 'browserify', gulp.parallel('copy')))
```

When I execute the `build_dev` task using `gulp build_dev` from the command line, I am given this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:121
    gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:121:19
  at doNTCallback0 (node.js:407:9)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:377:13)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:477:11)
  at startup (node.js:117:18)
  at node.js:951:3
```

How can I get this to work?

EDIT:
I am getting that same error with this file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('build_dev', function() {
  console.log(1);
})
```

Comment: Your error is on a line that you've not included in the snippet. Can you post your entire Gulpfile?

Comment: Hi Whymarrh, I edited the post. You can see that I simplified dramatically, but I still have the same error.

Comment: Ah, I see, the error is coming from Gulp itself. Have you tried a non-global installation of Gulp? Also, you say Gulp 4.0 when the latest version on npm is 3.9.0, how did you install Gulp?

Comment: I previously used `npm install gulpjs/gulp-cli#4.0 -g`. I was using an outdated version of Gulp, and, just now, to complete the upgrade I removed `/usr/local/bin/gulp.` and I am past this error! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to return from your function.

```
gulp.task('dev_urls', function() {
    return gulp.src([ 'app/index.js' ])
        .pipe()
}
```

Also make sure that gulp is installed correctly.

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/gulp
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
$ npm uninstall gulp

$ npm install gulpjs/gulp-cli#4.0 -g

# install Gulp 4 into your project
$ npm install gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0 --save-dev
```

Comment: At this point in time I'm getting errors with the steps AFTER 'npm uninstall gulp'. but got it to work just doing npm install gulp-cli -g